# Dining Philosopher problem Ada- Implementing ID Dispenser

Tags: ada

I have the following code, related to the dining philosopher problem. I am very new to Ada so am not sure about how to implement the Id_Dispenser package.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Id_Dispenser;
with Semaphores;   use Semaphores;

procedure Philos is

   No_of_Philos : constant Positive := 5; -- Number of philosophers
   Meditation   : constant Duration := 0.0;

   type Table_Ix is mod No_of_Philos;

   Forks : array (Table_Ix) of Binary_Semaphore (Initially_Available => True);

   package Index_Dispenser is new Id_Dispenser (Element => Table_Ix);
   use Index_Dispenser;

   task type Philo;
   task body Philo is

      Philo_Nr : Table_Ix; -- Philisopher number

   begin
      Dispenser.Draw_Id (Id => Philo_Nr);
      Put_Line ("Philosopher" & Table_Ix'Image (Philo_Nr) & " looks for forks.");
      Forks (Philo_Nr).Wait; delay Meditation; Forks (Philo_Nr + 1).Wait;
      Put_Line ("Philosopher" & Table_Ix'Image (Philo_Nr) & " eats.");
      Forks (Philo_Nr).Signal; Forks (Philo_Nr + 1).Signal;
      Put_Line ("Philosopher" & Table_Ix'Image (Philo_Nr) & " dropped forks.");
   end Philo;

   Table : array (Table_Ix) of Philo; pragma Unreferenced (Table);

begin
   null;
end Philos;
```

I have implemented the following semaphore, which I think should be correct

```
package body semaphores is
   protected body Binary_Semaphore is
      entry Wait when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Count := Count - 1;
      end Wait;
      
      entry Release when Count < 1 is 
      begin
         Count := Count + 1;
      end Signal
   end Binary_Semaphore;   
end semaphores;
```

What does the Id_Dispenser need?

Comment: You have `Dispenser.Draw_Id (Id => Philo_Nr);` What is `Dispenser`?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code,

```ada
type Table_Ix is mod No_of_Philos;
   ...
package Index_Dispenser is new Id_Dispenser (Element => Table_Ix);
```

we can tell that `Id_Dispenser` is a generic package with a formal type named `Element`, and that the formal type is modular:

```ada
generic
   type Element is mod <>;
package Id_Dispenser is
```

This

```ada
   Philo_Nr : Table_Ix; -- Philisopher number
begin
   Dispenser.Draw_Id (Id => Philo_Nr);
```

tells us that `Id_Dispenser` has some sort of component called `Dispenser` with a subprogram `Draw_Id` with an `out` parameter named `Id` which returns an `Element`.

Now, since this is a concurrent program, I'm going to guess that `Dispenser` is a protected object:

```ada
protected Dispenser is
   procedure Draw_Id (Id : out Element);
private
   ...
end Dispenser;
```

The private part could simply be an array of `Boolean` indexed by `Element`,

```ada
Available : array (Element) of Boolean := (others => True);
```

but unfortunately you can't have an anonymous array as a component, so you need a proper type, giving

```ada
generic
   type Element is mod <>;
package Id_Dispenser is
   type Availability is array (Element) of Boolean;
   protected Dispenser is
      procedure Draw_Id (Id : out Element);
   private
      Available : Availability := (others => True);
   end Dispenser;
end Id_Dispenser;
```

I'm not happy that the type `Availability` is visible, but the package now just needs implementing (!)

---

We could make `Availability` invisible by making `Id_Dispenser.Dispenser` a package, with `Availability` and the actual PO declared in the body. But that may be getting a little too purist for Ben’s context.

Comment: What is meant by this line?
Available : Availability := (others => True);
Thanks for the help! Im trying to implement it now

Comment: @Ben it is setting all other values in array to True. In this case entire array.

Comment: Thanks. I have the following code, which works, but only allows one philosopher to eat, as Id does not actually change for some reason.

package body Id_Dispenser is
   protected body Dispenser is
      procedure Draw_Id (Id : in out Element) is
      begin
        Id := Id+1;
      end Draw_Id;
   end Dispenser;
end Id_Dispenser;

Comment: The actual for `Id` is `Philo_Nr` in task type `Philo`, which is uninitialized, and each actual task has its own copy. You’re lucky that each of those copies was initially zero; could just as well have been `16#deadbeef#`. `Draw_Id` should have a plain `out` parameter, and the variable that gets incremented should be in `Id_Dispenser`’s body.

Comment: @SimonWright what is needed in the procedure draw_id that allows randomy drawing of ID

Comment: Ben, that’s a different question. Anyway, what would the use case be?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't really shorten identifiers, so you should have `task type Philosophers...` You can always use a renaming later on.

Shouldn't you model the forks and the philosophers? Each Philosopher as a task (hint array of task types).

Look at protected objects to model the forks.

Comment: This is almost certainly a classroom project; and the next topic will probably be to understand why the code deadlocks (which it does if `Meditation` is greater than 0.0, and may do if it is 0.0).

Answer (score 1):

`Id_dispenser` needs to implement a `Draw_ID` method.

Since the `Dispenser` variable is not declared here, it must presumably be declared in `Id_dispenser`. This hidden declaration is not very good style, as you can see it causes confusion; I would use a qualified name to make it obvious where it came from, as `Index_Dispenser.Dispenser` (which can then be renamed to reduce clutter in the rest of the code).

`Id_dispenser` may also need to provide an object factory method to initialise the `Dispenser` variable at its declaration.

Or, the intent may be that `Dispenser` will be the only one of its type, in which case you can  treat `Id_dispenser` as a singleton package with `Dispenser` as the only object.