# Ada synchronization- how to make code faster?

Tags: synchronization, ada

The protected object mechanisms can not only be used to share data, but also to synchronize
actions. Here comes a pattern which (attempts) to synchronize all tasks and release all of them
once all tasks are ready to proceed. The Count attribute on entries comes in handy for this purpose as it indicates how many tasks are currently waiting on this particular entry. Here we open
the entry Synchronize based on the number of waiting tasks:

```
with Ada.Task_Identification; use Ada.Task_Identification;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Synchronized_Action is
 No_Of_Tasks : constant Positive := 5;
 protected type Blockers (Group_Size : Positive) is
 entry Synchronize;
 end Blockers;
 protected body Blockers is
 entry Synchronize when Synchronize’Count = Group_Size is
 begin
 null;
 end Synchronize;
 end Blockers;
 Blocker : Blockers (No_Of_Tasks);
 task type In_Synchronized_Stages;
 task body In_Synchronized_Stages is
 begin
 Put_Line (“Task “ & Image (Current_Task) & “ starting up”);
 delay 1.0;
 Blocker.Synchronize;
 Put_Line (“Task “ & Image (Current_Task) & “ in stage 1”);
 delay 1.0;
 Blocker.Synchronize;
 Put_Line (“Task “ & Image (Current_Task) & “ in stage 2”);
 end In_Synchronized_Stages;
 Staged_Tasks : array (1 .. No_Of_Tasks) of In_Synchronized_Stages;
begin
 null;
end Synchronized_Action;
```

Now I have to admit that this program looks better than it runs: It “hangs” - or at least it seems
to stall for all but the most patient users. The idea of the program is that all tasks re-synchronize between stages, such that no task should every work in a later stage while some other
task is still busy in an earlier stage.
Repair this program such that it indeed shows the intended behaviour and runs to completion.
Hint: What is the temporal sequence in which you expect to see outputs on the screen? What
is the rhythm in which outputs actually turn up? How can this possibly happen? … now you
show see the bug (right?) and can repair it.

The following implementation does run to completion, but takes about 0.5 seconds. What could be done to make this much faster?

```
with Ada.Task_Identification; use Ada.Task_Identification;
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Synchronized_Action is

   No_Of_Tasks : constant Positive := 5;

   protected type Blockers (Group_Size : Positive) is

      entry Synchronize;
   private
      Triggered : Boolean := False;

   end Blockers;

   protected body Blockers is

      entry Synchronize when Synchronize'Count = Group_Size or Triggered is

      begin
         if Synchronize'Count = 0 then
            Triggered := False;
         else
            Triggered := True;
         end if;
      end Synchronize;

   end Blockers;

   Blocker : Blockers (No_Of_Tasks);

   task type In_Synchronized_Stages;

   task body In_Synchronized_Stages is

   begin
      Put_Line ("Task " & Image (Current_Task) & " starting up");
      delay 0.0;

      Blocker.Synchronize;

      Put_Line ("Task " & Image (Current_Task) & " in stage 1");
      delay 0.0;

      Blocker.Synchronize;

      Put_Line ("Task " & Image (Current_Task) & " in stage 2");

   end In_Synchronized_Stages;

   Staged_Tasks : array (1 .. No_Of_Tasks) of In_Synchronized_Stages; pragma Unreferenced (Staged_Tasks);

begin
   null;
end Synchronized_Action;
```

Comment: What takes "about 0.5 seconds"? Running this with `time` on Linux reports 16 ms "real" (elapsed) time. Note that almost all of the elapsed time for such a program is doing output.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly sophisticated code, compared to the difficulties you’re encountering in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63498510/40851), so I’m wondering whether they are class problems i.e. homework?

The reason why your first version fails is that the entry condition is reevaluated after every activation, so that when the first task completes there are only 4 tasks in the entry queue.

I can’t help feeling there may be a related issue in the second version, at any rate if the queuing policy ([ARM D.4](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-4.html)) isn’t FIFO_Queuing.